# Creating Multiple JButtons in Swing - Neaten this code

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm developing an application using Swing. My program involves me having an individual button for each letter of the alphabet. 
My code looks really messy at the beginning of the program when I create all these buttons. Is there any way to neaten (and shorten) this? Perhaps with an array of chars and a for loop? I'm not quite sure how though...

```
final JButton btnA = new JButton("a");
final JButton btnB = new JButton("b");
final JButton btnC = new JButton("c");
final JButton btnD = new JButton("d");
final JButton btnE = new JButton("e");
final JButton btnF = new JButton("f");
final JButton btnG = new JButton("g");
final JButton btnH = new JButton("h");
final JButton btnI = new JButton("i");
final JButton btnJ = new JButton("j");
final JButton btnK = new JButton("k");
final JButton btnL = new JButton("l");
final JButton btnM = new JButton("m");
final JButton btnN = new JButton("n");
final JButton btnO = new JButton("o");
final JButton btnP = new JButton("p");
final JButton btnQ = new JButton("q");
final JButton btnR = new JButton("r");
final JButton btnS = new JButton("u");
final JButton btnT = new JButton("t");
final JButton btnU = new JButton("u");
final JButton btnV = new JButton("v");
final JButton btnW = new JButton("w");
final JButton btnX = new JButton("x");
final JButton btnY = new JButton("y");
final JButton btnZ = new JButton("z");
```

Comment: Yes, you can have an array and a loop.  What seems to be not clear?

Comment: Hint the ascii character of `a` is 97

Comment: How will I set the names of the JButtons like this though? I am using them a lot throughout the program and must be able to make reference to each one.

Comment: Short answer is, don't, use the `actionCommand` property of the `JButton` to set the "character" it represents or simply use `getText`

Comment: you can use a HashMap or maybe a TreeMap such as each char will point to the button object, example map.put('a', btn[i]) in your loop

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy store all the buttons in some sort of an array and loop through the alphabet

```
ArrayList<JButton> btns = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    for(char alpha = 'a'; alpha <= 'z';++alpha)
    {
        btns.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(alpha)));
    }
```

Comment: If you want the buttons to have "names" you can even do it with a HashMap and use key=>value,  "btn" + String.valueOf(alpha).toUpperCase() => new JButton(String.valueOf(alpha)). or something like that...